# Lucene numeric range search with LUKE

Tags: indexing, lucene, luke

I have a number of numeric Lucene indexed fields:

```
60000
78500
105000
```

If I use LUKE to query for 78500 as follows:

```
price:78500
```

It returns the correct record, however if I try to return all three record as a range I get no results.

```
price:[60000 TO 105000]
```

I realise this is due to padding as numbers are treated strings by Lucene however I just wish to know what I should be putting into LUKE to return the three records.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried: price:["60000" TO "105000"]

Comment: Thanks Joel, yeah I tried this and still no results returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I used for this was that the values inputted for price needed to be added to the index in padded form. Then I would just query the new padded value which works great. Therefore the new values in the index were:

```
060000
078500
105000
```

This solution was tied into an Examine search issue for Umbraco so there is a thread on the Forum of how to implement a numeric based range search if anyone requires this it is located here with a walk through end to end.

[Umbraco Forum Thread](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/16888-Examine-Search-Range-Values)

Comment: This is probably the best solution if you want users to be able to enter the numeric range query as text. If you have a different way to gather input that you should use the `NumericRangeQuery` class and use it to construct your query by hand rather that using the `QueryParser`.

Answer (score 11):

If the fields are indexed as NumericField you must use "Use XML Query Parser" option in query parser tab and the 3.5 version of Luke:

https://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/detail?name=lukeall-3.5.0.jar&can=2&q=

An example of query with a string and **numeric field** is:

```
<BooleanQuery>
<Clause fieldName="colour" occurs="must">
    <TermQuery>rojo</TermQuery>
</Clause>
<Clause fieldName="price" occurs="must">
    <NumericRangeQuery type="int" lowerTerm="4000" upperTerm="5000" />
</Clause>
</BooleanQuery>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Zero padding won't come into this particular query since all the numbers you've shown have the same number of digits
2. The range query you've shown has too many zeros on the second part of the range
3. So the query for the data you've shown would be `price:[10500 TO 78500]`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Apologies, the last figure was meant to read 105000, I will edit now. I have managed to resolve this so will post an answer now. Many thanks for your tips with this though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume these fields are indexed as `NumericField`s. The problem with them is that Lucene/Luke does not know how to parse numeric queries automatically. You need to override Lucene's `QueryParser` and provide your own logic how these numbers should be interpreted.

As far as I know, Luke allows sticking in your custom parser, it just need to be present in the CLASSPATH.

Have a look at this thread on Lucene mailing list:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201102.mbox/%3CAANLkTi=XUpyw09tcbjuTzNRpMJa730Cq-6_1agMAjYz6@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thanks very much for this information, I have managed to resolve this now.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the OP's question as it states why what the OP wanted to do **does not work** (automatically interpreting string input as a numeric range query).